# PHP, PDO, is this function secure if not what else i need to cover here

Tags: php, pdo

the PDO conneciton is:

```
  public function __construct(){
    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dms","root","");
    $this->conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
}
```

now here is the function to get the result of the required rows.

```
public function getAny() {
            $stmt9 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name);
            $stmt9->execute();
            return $stmt9 = $stmt9->fetchAll();
            }
```

after this on view we will fetch out the rows after running the function.
this is the view.php

```
         $doc = $organ->getAny();
         if(count($doc)){
            foreach($doc as $data){
                    echo $data['id'] . "<br />";
                            echo $data['nameARABIC'] . "<br />";
                    }
```

is this view.php secure and what else should i do for securing more.
regards

Comment: This question is probably more suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: All of this is already explained, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: i can not use htmlspecialchars, because if i do it my text is arabic and it will not show it.

Comment: @abas_rafiq , so you need rephrase your question or create new one.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is pretty safe, though I suggest you to use "SET NAMES UTF8" instead of "set character set". OR better, if you're on php >= 5.3.6 you can use the "charset" parameter INSIDE the DSN. [**Further information**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

Also, to avoid SQL Injections, you should ALWAYS avoid putting user's input inside a string, then using it for SQL. E.g. if self::$table_name is a user input (though it's not) you should be careful and do one of two things:

- Escape through [PDO::quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)
- Use prepared statement

<s>In the end:</s>

```
return $stmt9 = $stmt9->fetchAll();
```

Will return whether or not the assignation was completed (either, true or false, not the content of $stmt9->fetchAll() ).

As pointed out by YourCommonSense, the behaviour depicted in the last part, is not correct.